# how to get the .data element of a child div when clicked

Tags: jquery

I have three images that each have some info stored in their div when they were created.  Each stored in the div id = track#.  I have the click handler on the parent and I'd like to get the data back from the specific image that was clicked.  For some reason I'm only getting the data from the first image no matter which one I click.

```
      <div class="row" id="albumMenu">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" id="track1" >
          <img class="coverart" id="track1-img" src="" ></img>
          <p class="albumTitles" id="track1-title">/<p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" id="track2" >
          <img class="coverart" id="track2-img" src=""></img>
          <p class="albumTitles" id="track2-title">/<p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" id="track3" >
          <img class="coverart" id="track3-img" src=""></img>
          <p class="albumTitles" id="track3-title">/<p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div> <!-- /row -->
```

Here is how I've been looking for the data.

```
$("#albumMenu").click(function(){
  console.log($(this).children().data());
});
```

Comment: Do you want to get info on image click? Then target class coverart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the child info, but you are selection the parent.

```
$("[id^='track']").on('click',function(){
   console.log($(this).data());
})
```